# can't set SKPhysicsBody inside a function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I created a class that defines a ball of kind `SKShapeNode`. Inside the class' `init()` method I try to initialize the ball's `physicsBody` properties. Unfortunately, the function doesn't really work - it doesn't init its properties. I'm not sure what the problem is, or if I can initialize these properties inside the function.

Here is my code:

```
class BallNode: SKShapeNode {
    var radius:CGFloat = 0
    var color:UIColor?
    var strokeWidth:CGFloat = 0
    private var _name:String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.fillColor = ranColor()
        self.setPhysics(body: self)
        self.lineWidth = strokeWidth

    }
```

Here is the function I wrote inside the class:

```
    func setPhysics(body: SKShapeNode) {
        body.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        print("gravity = F")
        body.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
        body.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

I know the function is running because it prints in the console:

> gravity = F

But it doesn't really work because the ball is affected by gravity (its default).

What am I dong wrong?

update:
if I set those properties inside my `touchesBegan` it's working. for example:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let positionOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)


        let ball = BallNode(radius: 65)
        ball.Name = "BALL"
        print(ball.Name)

        ball.position = positionOfTouch
        ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        self.addChild(ball)
```